# Lost/blocked my credit card, can't buy any apps because of billing info

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I lost (and locked) my credit card. Now whenever I want to buy an app from the iOS store, the transaction fails. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: what do you want us to do or to tell you ? get a new valid credit card and enter it in to your Apple account.

Answer (score 2):

From iTunes on your Mac: click on user icon on the top bar () > Account informations -> type your password -> billing information then remove your old card and insert your new card.

From iPhone: App Store -> scroll bottom -> Apple ID: your mail -> Show Apple ID type your password -> billing information then remove your old card and insert your new card.